# Simplify $\frac{1-\sqrt{x+1}}{1+\sqrt{x+1}}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify  $\dfrac{1-\sqrt{x+1}}{1+\sqrt{x+1}}$.

I did times {1− (√x +1)} under and above =  {1− (√x +1)} {1− (√x +1)} / 1 . I can not get it smaller. This is wrong, please help.

Comment: I do not see how your answer helps. I do now know what it is called.

Comment: That's not an equation. An equation has an equals sign.

Comment: tell what it is then not what not it is :/

Comment: What is the problem you have to solve/ the question you have to answer? An equation is something of the form $f(x)=g(x)$ (when dealing with formulas in $x$). Your 'equation' however doesn't have an '$=$' sign, so isn't an equation. Maybe you just have to simplify or take a limit? Also, please use $\LaTeX$ formatting.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX

Comment: I need to make under part rational and simplify at smallest. My English is not so good

Comment: @Sonja It was unclear what your question was. It is an expression, but it is not clear what you wanted to do with it.

Comment: I have 1 answer it is oke you do not understand. Someone understand

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{1-\sqrt{x+1}}{1+\sqrt{x+1}}=\dfrac{(1-\sqrt{x+1})(1-\sqrt{x+1})}{(1+\sqrt{x+1})(1-\sqrt{x+1})}=\dfrac{(1-\sqrt{x+1})^2}{-x}$

Can you complete now?

Comment: that is what I already did ;/? I did times 1− (√x +1)} under and boven and then I can not make smaller

Comment: @Sonja : Does that help now?

Comment: Thank you for help. I try to do verder.

Comment: @pascalhein : yes... thank you :)

Comment: Please tell why under is -x? I think under is only 1 left over. √x-√x, no x left.

Comment: what formula  do you know for $(a+b)(a-b)$?

Comment: a^2+ab+ba+b^2= a^2+2ab+b^2

Comment: No No... for $(a+b)(a+b)$ you have $a^2+2ab+b^2$... I have asked for $(a+b)(a-b)$

Comment: sorry I see wrong.  a^2-ab+ab-b^2=a^2-b^2

Comment: yes... so now, what does $(1+\sqrt{x+1})(1-\sqrt{x-1})$ equals to?

Comment: x^1/2 * x^1/2= x and 1*1=1 = x

Comment: -x I see. x^1/2 * -x^1/2= -x. You help good. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you

Comment: I can not get the smaller answer? it is done?

Comment: Yes.. It is done...

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro : Thank you and  :)